Inductive Hypothesis is wrongly generated
(Compiling code at the end)
So, I'm trying to prove progress for a small language:
Theorem progess
  : forall {n : nat} (A : Types) (s : Store n) (e_l : Expression A) (g : Gamma)
  , exists (e_r : Expression (rtype A))
  , <| g | s |> :- (e_l ==> e_r)
  .
Proof.
  intros sz A s [ n (*i*)| A' g' e_x (* closure *)].
  (* i *)
  - admit.
  (* closure *)
  -{ induction e_x as [i_x | closure_x   g'' body IH].
    - admit.
    - (* here *) admit.
   }
Admitted.

Nevertheless, the IH is written with the g'amma of the intros, instead of the g''amma of the induction:
IH :
  forall g : Gamma,
  @ex (Expression (rtype closure_x))
    (fun e_r : Expression (rtype closure_x) =>
     @Env_f sz g s Prop
       (fun (g'0 : Gamma) (s' : Store sz) =>
        @RValue closure_x sz g'0 s' (@Closure closure_x g' body) e_r))
                                                        ^
                                                Gamma of the intros

instead of
IH :
  forall g : Gamma,
  @ex (Expression (rtype closure_x))
    (fun e_r : Expression (rtype closure_x) =>
     @Env_f sz g s Prop
       (fun (g'0 : Gamma) (s' : Store sz) =>
        @RValue closure_x sz g'0 s' (@Closure closure_x g'' body) e_r))
                                                        ^
                                      The gamma from the induction 

Any idea why is this happening?
Require Export Coq.Strings.String.
Require Export Coq.Arith.Arith_base.
Require Export Coq.Init.Logic.

Set Default Goal Selector "!".

Inductive Types : Type :=
  | Z
  | Fun  (t_p t_r : Types)
  | Lazy (t_b : Types).

Definition rtype (t : Types) : Types :=
  match t with
  | Z           => Z
  | Fun t_p t_r => Fun t_p t_r
  | Lazy t_b    => t_b
  end.

Inductive Store' (F : Types -> Type) :  nat -> Type :=.
Inductive Gamma' (loc : Type) (F : Types -> Type) : Type :=.
Inductive Expression : Types -> Type :=
  | i : nat -> Expression Z
  | Closure  
    {A   : Types             }
    (g'  : Gamma' nat Expression )
    (e_x : Expression A      )
    : Expression A
  .

Definition Gamma     := Gamma'     nat Expression.
Definition Store     := Store'     Expression.

Definition Env_f
  { n : nat    }
  (g  : Gamma  )
  (s  : Store n)
  : forall (r : Type), (Gamma -> Store n -> r) -> r 
  := fun _ h => h g s.

Notation "<| g | s |>"    := 
  (Env_f g s) 
  (at level 0, g at level 97).
Notation "g :- e" := 
  (g _ e) 
  (at level 98).

Inductive RValue : forall 
  {A : Types} 
  {n' : nat}  
  (g : Gamma) 
  (s : Store n') 
  (l : Expression A)  
  (r : Expression (rtype A))
  , Prop := .

Notation " e_1 '==>' e_2 " := (fun g' s' => RValue g' s' e_1 e_2) (at level 50, left associativity).

Theorem progess
  : forall {n : nat} (A : Types) (s : Store n) (e_l : Expression A) (g : Gamma)
  , exists (e_r : Expression (rtype A))
  , <| g | s |> :- (e_l ==> e_r)
  .
Proof.
  intros sz A s [ n (*i*)| A' g' e_x (* closure *)].
  (* i *)
  - admit.
  (* closure *)
  -{ induction e_x as [i_x | closure_x   g'' body IH].
    - admit.
    - (* here *) admit.
   }
Admitted.

Compute "done!"%string.
```


Coq will not touch the context surrounding the thing you do the induction on. If your g' changes during the induction (here you want it to become g''), you need to revert it before doing the induction, so that the induction hypothesis becomes forall g', ... and you can apply this to g''.
